# Use same class as multiple Bolts in Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm

I'm new to Apache Storm and have been facing issues with the capacity of multiple bolts.

So I have a Class **X**, which is used as a **Bolt**. Can there be any bottleneck if we use the same class with the separate instance as multiple **Bolts** each having a different **parallelismHint**, like below:

```
builder.setBolt(BOLT-1, new X());
builder.setBolt(BOLT-2, new X());
builder.setBolt(BOLT-3, new X());
```

Each of above the Bolt is bound to separate Spout.

Thanks in advance!
Saurabh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your `X` class doesn't have static state, this won't be a problem. Each `.setBolt` causes more instances of `X` to be spawned, so the bolts are going to be independent.